# Remember selection and act accordingly on next launch

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm building an application that asks the user to select one option (41 languages) from multiple choices on application launch and in bottom there is a toggle button wich is off by default. If the user sets it on "on" I want my application to remember this selection and go to that language option at launch, ignoring the language selection page.

I'm pretty new to android development, I would appreciate if the answer would include some example code so I can modify it and learn while modifying it.

Thank you.

Comment: use SharedPreferences

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) is what you need.

```
// here you get an instance of SharedPreferences for your app
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// editor is required to apply changes to existing SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.apply();

// this is a way that you take stored values back from the SharedPreferences
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```